# Writing simple SMTP server in python

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to write a simple smtp server program. I've written a simple smtp client (in C#) which sends an email. I've tested the program with [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/). So far it all works fine.

I'd also like to write my own simple program which receives the email (instead of smtp4dev). I've tried a number of different code snippets (eg: [Here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/96/)) that I've found around the web but I can't seem to get them working.

I've also tried using [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac).

To start with I can see using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) that the port numbers in the code are not the ones being used.

I get the feeling that I'm missing something conceptual though and heading in the wrong direction.

**EDIT**

Here's the C# code in case you are interested

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com.au");
mail.To.Add("soslab@soslab.lab");
mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;            

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("LOCALHOST", 26); 
smtp.EnableSsl = false;

try
{
    smtp.Send(mail);                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

---

here's the python code

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class EmailServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'a'

    def run():
        foo = EmailServer(('localhost', 26), None)
        try:
            asyncore.loop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

[image: mail tcp]

Comment: Can you post some code or some errors that you are getting. It is hard to help when you are not being specific about your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this program runs fine when I run it from the command line

```
import smtpd
import asyncore
import winsound

class PYEmailServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        smtpd.SMTPServer.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        winsound.Beep(2500, 1000)

def run():
    foo = PYEmailServer(('localhost', 26), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        foo.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    run()
```

It does not work when I run it from IDLE. (C# program just throws an exception like the service isnt there). I dont know why this would be, but I have my original problem working.

Answer (score 0):

To test your smtp server you need to set the smtpclient object on another terminal

```
import smtplib
smtpclient=smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1',8001)
smtpClient.sendmail('sender@gmail.com','recivers@gmail.com','sadfsdf')
```

Comment: hi thanks, I can send mail no problem. I want to be able to receive.